# Get element in embed tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have web site which looks simplified like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Some content</p>
        <p>Some more content</p>
        <div class="embeddedObject">
            <embed>
                #document
                <html>
                    <body>
                        <!-- I want this video tag! -->
                        <video>...</video>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </embed>
        </div>
    <body>
<html>
```

I can get the embed tag with this:

```
var objects = $( ".embeddedObject" );
var myEmbedTag = $(objects[0]).find("embed");
```

But I am unable to get the video tag inside this element. None of what I tried worked:

```
// Nope...
var myVideoTag = $(myEmbedTag).find("video");

// Nope...
var myVideoTag = $(myEmbedTag[0]).find("video");

// Nope...
var myVideoTag = $(myEmbedTag[0]).contents().find("video");
```

How can I get the video tag in my embed element?

Comment: `$(objects[0]).("embed");` this is Syntax error.

Comment: `$("embed").contents().find("video");` maybe?

Comment: @dfsq you are right. I forgot to provide the code to get the `objects` variable. I updated my post: `var objects = $( ".embeddedObject" );`

Comment: @ThomasUhrig No, I mean, this is syntactically incorrect notation `obj.(`. Check your console.

Comment: @dfsq Ohhh I see. Sorry, my mistake. It should be `find`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".embeddedObject").find("video").attr("id");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/G7RF5/)