# Get an element in an <embed> tag

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I'm a beginner in Javascript and i'm trying to get an element from an embed tag. This embed tag contains a pdf.
I want to get the button "next page" from the pdf viewer, and simulate a click on it, in order to automaticly scroll to the next page of the pdf.

My HTML code is something like this (really simplified) :

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="display-zone">
      <embed id="myPdf" src="./myPdf.pdf">
        #document
          <html>
            <body>
              <!-- The button I want to get in my JavaScript -->
              <button id="next" class="toolbarButton pageDown"></button>
            </body>
          </html>
        </embed>
      </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

My JS code to print the pdf viewer on the web page :

```
affichage.innerHTML = "<embed class=\"media\" id=\""+ongletsMedias[i].firstChild.data+"\" src= \""+ongletsMedias[i].firstChild.data+"\" width= \"1000\" height= \"800\">";
        // ongletsMedias[i].firstChild.data equals to "myPdf"
        t = 5000; // time before starting pdfDefile()
        setTimeout(pdfDefile,t,ongletsMedias[i].firstChild.data,i,1); //call the function to scroll pdf pages
```

And finally my function `pdfDefile()` that I'm calling in order to scroll the pdf pages :

```
function pdfDefile(dir,i,page) {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var t = 0;
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 && checkbox.checked) {
    document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = this.responseText; // display the number of pages of my pdf
    var t = 5000;
    if (page < parseInt(this.responseText)) { //test for recursive call
      /*HERE is where I want to get the "next" button */
      setTimeout(pdfDefile,t,dir,i,page+1);// recall this function while there is a next page to display
    } else {
      setTimeout(jouerMedia,t,i+1);// call the main fuction, no problem here
    }
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "nbPagesPDF.php?pages="+dir, true);
xhttp.send();
```

}

I already look at an existing topic ([Get element in embed tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24280414/get-element-in-embed-tag)), but I can't make it work in my JS.

So please, can you help me to make my code great again (may it have been ;-) ) ?

Regards

Comment: the topic you was looking for is for jQuery, are you using jQuery?
And where is the code you have tried?

Comment: `document.getElementById('next').click();` ? As `id` should be unique

Comment: @CalvinNunes I'm mainly using Javascript, but I tried this solution with jQuery.  I tried this : `$(".embeddedObject").find("#next")`.

Comment: you don't have an element with `class='embeddedObject'` , you should try  `$("#myPdf").find("#next")`

Comment: @CalvinNunes I tried your solution with this selector, and it doesn't work. And I prefer to not use jQuery at the time.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I cannot access the `next` id, because it is inside the embed tag, and I cannot access a simple element from the `<embed>` tag

Comment: So, can you add a working snippet of your current code, it will help a lot to people here understand your code and try to help. (edit the question and use the `<>` button to add snippet)

Comment: @CalvinNunes I've done it, if you need more working snippet of my code, please ask, it would be a pleasure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var embed = document.getElementById('myPdf');
// Wait for document to load inside embed element
embed.on('load', function() {
    embed.getElementById('next').click();
});
```

(I am using jQuery in this example for adding the event listener, not sure if you are using it on your project?)

Without jQuery you could do:

```
var embed = document.getElementById('myPdf');
embed.onload = function() {
    embed.getElementById('next').click();
};
```

It might be possible you can not trigger a click event on that button since a user action often must have taken place to trigger click's from js.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, but i'm not using jQuery jQuery anymore. When I call the embed tag, I'm calling my function that find the 'next' button with a setTimeout(function,5000). So I think my document is loaded when I call my function.

Comment: You can not be sure if the timeout will be enough in all cases, users with slower connection might need more time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I solved my problem by calling the page number that I want to load in the url of the pdf. In my case, my web site will only be loaded in a local area, so my setTimeout() works fine.